# Finding cyclic vector of a representation of $C^*$- algebra

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory

I am reading *functional analysis* by conway. the location of that Example is chapter VIII, Example 5.5.[image: 5.5]

In a further excercise in *Conwey's book* they asked about the cyclic vectors of this representation. 
**A representation $\pi:\mathscr{A}\rightarrow \mathscr{B(H)} $ of a $C^*$- algebra $\mathscr{A}$ is cyclic if there is a vector e in $\mathscr{H}$ such that $cl[\pi(\mathscr{A})e]=\mathscr{H} $ ; e is said to be a cyclic vector for the representation $\pi$.**
I am confused about the positive Borel measure. Is there any relation between compactness of X with $\mu(X)$? Is that finite ?
If it was finite then we can take $f=1 \in \mathscr{B}(L^2(\mu))$ which will be such a cyclic vector.

Comment: Yes $\mu(X)$ is finite and $1$ is an *example* of cyclic vector, but may be Conway asked for *all* of them(?)

Comment: Yeah they asked for all of them.

Comment: @AnneBauval but usually positive Borel measure doesn't mean that measure of compact set is finite instead if it was regular? Is that Correct?

Comment: Usually but not always: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_measure

Comment: @AnneBauval What about Conway? Does he assume locally finiteness?

Comment: "What about Conway?" You should know better than me, I don't have you book. I don't understand your other comment. Functions belong to $C(X)$ and cyclic vectors to $\mathcal H$; neither belongs to $\mathcal B(\mathcal H).$

Comment: Can you verify that all $f \in \mathscr{L}^2(\mu)$ such that $1/f\in \mathscr{L}^2(\mu)$ is a cyclic vector here. I edited this. Can you check now.

Comment: First type your proof or counterexample, and then we can check it.